# Why might I get this error on a script that has been running fine for a year? - sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

Tags: linux, rsync, sudo, snapshot

I have a script that runs nightly. The userid is set up in sudoers to perform these functions. I do not intend to disable "Defaults requiretty", particularly without knowing why it's suddenly a problem now.

Here's what it does with sudo:

```
sudo lvcreate -- size 19000M –snapshot –name snap_u /dev/mapper/vg_u-lvu
sudo mount /dev/vg_u/snap_u /snapshot

sudo rsync -av --delete --bwlimit=12000 –exclude usr/spoolhold --exclude email --exclude tempfile    /snapshot/    /u1/prev/dir

sudo umount /snapshot
sudo lvremove -f /dev/vg_u/snap_u
```

For the past few weeks it doesn't work most of the time. Sometimes when I run the commands "manually" it works fine. When it fails I see this message filling the log file:

**sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo**

The problem began when I switched some other scripts for a remote backup. The only things I changed in this script were comments. This script is invoked by an application program that uses ‘nohup’ to run it in the background.

During my testing I killed the process to stop it from running in the background when I wanted to run it again immediately. Since then I’ve had this problem. So, my questions are these:

1. Could this error be related to ‘killing’ those processes (Maybe I killed the wrong one)?
2. Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: Here is some more information about the problem. There are multiple sudo commands in this script. The 1st 2 run without incident. (Create snapshot & mount snapshot).  The 3rd one (rsync) is what brings up this message. I checked sudoers and see that rsync is in the NOPASSWD list. Even more mysteriously, the script works about every 3rd time it's run.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Could this error be related to ‘killing’ those processes (Maybe I killed the wrong one)?

No

> 2) Any ideas for a solution?

This is related to `requiretty` configuration option in `/etc/sudoers`. It probably changed in there or in default during some of the updates. Set it to `off` and you should be good.

Comment: So, you're saying that the default for requiretty may have initially been off and then an update switched it on? But wouldn't that mean that every time I tried to do this it would bomb?  Right now, it works sometimes. So, there is something intermittent about it.

Comment: If it works "sometimes", it is very weird and probably different issue ...

Comment: Yeah. That's what I thought all along, that it's not related to the requiretty setting. I'm trying to isolate it. I'll post back if I find a common thread.

Comment: I'm logging things in great detail now to isolate the problem. But, it only makes it more mysterious. This script runs multiple sudo commands. The first 2 run without incident. (creating the snapshot & then mounting it). The 3rd sudo is the rsync and that is where the first error message comes up. Every sudo after that has the same problem.

Comment: I think I might be narrowing this down. This script is running as 'nohup' so I've been trying to tie it to other processes running at the same time to see if there's a problem there. I discovered if I changed 'sleep' timing it would start the rsync and get this error after a number of files: **rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(546) [sender=3.0.6]**. Does it seem reasonable that my problems are associated with other processes that are running at the same time?